# Is there any way to use compilerOptions or something similar for setting up base URL in JavaScript? (WebStorm IDE)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webstorm

In TypeScript we can set `compilerOptions` for setting up base URL like this

```
     // tsconfig.json

     "compilerOptions": {
        "paths": {
            "src/*": ["*"],
            "utility/*": ["utility/*"],
            "routes/*": ["routes/*"],
         }
      }


      // component.tsx

      import TestRoute from 'routes/testRoute'
```

Now there are some npm package that also allow us to set up base URL. But those also have some problems. So is there any way to set up base URL within package.json or any other convenient way?

Comment: Do you mean a [jsconfig.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig) file?

Comment: Webstorm has some issues with  jsconfig.json. Base URL doesn't work as expected.

Comment: what is this base URL supposed to be used for?

Comment: @lena check the component.tsx file import

Comment: hmm... If you are using `.tsx`, why don't the `tsconfig.json` path mappings work? Another way to get absolute paths resolved relative to some certain folder is marking this folder as *Resource root*

Comment: I am not using typescript. Typescript has this feature integrated and it does not cause any problem. I am trying to find something similar for JavaScript